# Convert Socket to String and vice versa

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm socket programming for Android (in Java).  How can I convert my socket to a string and convert that string representation back to a socket?

For example, consider a `Socket ss`. What I want is some thing like this:

```
String strss = ss.tostring();
```

and later

```
Socket s = new Socket(strss);
```

I want to save the Socket (i.e. the details needed to recreate that socket later) into a database (as a string) and after that I need to reconvert it to Socket to use it in my app!

Comment: What do you wnat to achieve by converting socket to string. It does not seems logical.

Comment: A socket can be used to create and maintain a connection to another socket or machine. It is not a `String`. The string you normally do use with a socket is a host, so you may use e.g. `getInetAddress().getHostName()` and use that to setup another `Socket`

Comment: I want to save Socket into database (as string )  and after that I need to reConvert it to Socket to use it in my app !

Comment: Serializing sockets is a bad idea. Just store the address.

Comment: Why don't you keep a map of sockets.  That was as you need them you can simply look them up in the map.

Comment: On stack exchange it is better to edit your question with the information requested, that way comments can be tidied up (deleted) once their points are addressed.

Comment: It is disappointing that most of the answers here seem more interested in criticising the question and making some *clever* point than they are in answering the underlying question. I think it is quite clear what *pooyan* wants to do, and just because *pooyan* didn't know quite what to ask for or express him/herself very well, doesn't give anyone the excuse to be rude or judgemental. Remember folks - [Be Nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 5):

Strange question but you can extract the info you need to recreate the socket from a string.
Without error checking etc:

To string:

```
Socket s = ...;
String hostAndPort = s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
hostAndPort = hostAndPort + ":" + s.getPort();
```

then back:

```
String host = hostAndPort.substring(0, hostAndPort.indexOf(':'));
int port = Integer.parseInt(hostAndPort.substring(hostAndPort.indexOf(':') + 1));
Socket s = new Socket(host, port);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to save Socket into database (as string )

That is not possible.

You are welcome to save the host and port you used to open a socket to a database.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution , but i was hoping Whether there is a better way .

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn a socket into a string, except as a simple summary. Instead, you should send data over the socket.

```
try{
Socket ss=new Socket();
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out=PrintWriter(ss.getOutputStream()));
String line=in.readLine(); //reads a line, repeat as necessary
out.println("foo"); //Writes a line
} catch (IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output buffering is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I think you don't get my goal . I now how to read and write with socket , but I want to save the Socket as String and after that when I need it , I want to reConvert it to Socket and use it in my app !!!

Comment: You didn't *explain* your goal clearly. If you want to serialize, *don't* serialize a socket.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save a socket into a database. It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

To recreate a socket later, you just need the *host address* and *port number*.

- If each existing socket has a different *host address* and *port number* then you will need to store both in your database:

  - If you have no choice about storing all the data in a single string, then you will need to encode both host address and port number in that string, in the [way suggested by Mattias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355532/42473) or something similar.
  - It would be better though, to store the *host address* and the *port number* in the database separately, that way you do not have the added complication of creating and parsing the strings later.
- If your socket is always opened to the same port however, you could just save the *host address* in the database.

For example, to get the *host address*:

```
String strss = ss.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
```

then to recreate the socket:

```
Socket s = new Socket(strss, KNOWN_PORT);
```