# how to make an if statement then send a message

Tags: java, if-statement, message

How would i make it so that if the input from the user is yes, then send the messaage You Successfully hunted a cow!

```
System.out.println("Would you like to hunt a cow?");
System.out.print("yes or no?");
String a = kbReader.next();
System.out.println("You successfully hunted a cow!")
```

Comment: You shouldn't use Java to kill cows.  I would suggest a functional language like Haskell. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29

Comment: Have a look at [how and what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: edited, im really sorry about that.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Amazingly, there doesn't seem to be a question about "how to write an if statement" to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @JeffGohlke it's kind of another wonder in SO, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355365/convert-socket-to-string-and-vise-versa) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554491/intel-i7-replacement-and-possible-programming) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208688/is-this-a-java-bug-in-integer-parseint) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554011/java-login-assistance), also I've got one in "Superuser" he wanted the win8 sources! unfortunately removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    ...
}
```

(or `equals` if you want to match `"yes"` exactly)

Comment: @Oxide_Sickness Just for future reference, many people use `==` for objects and strings. It should only be used for numbers, booleans, and char values, really. `equals(` should be used in all other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really what you need:

```
if ("yes".equals(a)) {
        System.out.println("You successfully killed a cow!")

}
```

Note the reverse check of string literal versus the input to avoid NPE.

Comment: @arshajii u won in timing by few seconds

Comment: No I mean you don't need a null check with yoda conditions.

Comment: +1 live, Congratulations, you have killed the cow successfully, see you at next level, time to kill a elephant :D

Answer (score 1):

user the equals method. for Strings, it simply checks if the strings have the same value

```
if(a.equals("yes")){
     System.out.println("You successfully killed a cow!")
}
else{
  //do whatever
}
```